Movie with a snake-like monster escaping from a borehole in Antarctica?
I'm trying to look for a movie in which a snake-like monster escapes from a borehole in Antarctica.
I saw the movie years ago in television so I can't remember the details, but it certainly can't have been released after 2017. I don't think it's from the 80s or anything either, as the monster was VFX (no recollection if they were any good).
The only thing I can remember is a scene, probably near the end, where the remaining crew tries to escape in a plane/helicopter but the monster somehow got in and pierces one of the pilots with the end of its tail. Also, of course, this is a massively oversized creature.

Arctic predator? https://i.sstatic.net/26xYHbdM.png

This is New Alcatraz (2001), AKA Boa.

As a result of a drilling accident, a giant man-eating boa constrictor is released into a maximum security prison in Antarctica.

The film is mostly set within a maximum-security prison called New Alcatraz, located in the Antarctic.
As the result of a drilling operation, a giant prehistoric snake is released from a state of suspended animation within a hollow rock deep underground and proceeds to kill several people in the prison.
A unit of soldiers, plus two palaeontologists, are flown in on a military plane to deal with the situation.
Near the end of the film, some of the characters use the plane to escape from the prison, but the snake manages to get into the plane as well and impales one of the pilots with its tail.




Damn, pipped me by 5s. Good find!

That was quick! This is what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Loved that movie. Especially Mark Sheppard.

The climax of this film gives me strong Aliens vibes, what with the snake sneaking onto the plane like the Alien Queen, and the pilot getting impaled by a tail like Bishop. Some of the characters also make use of motion detectors in an earlier scene, in a manner that is again reminiscent of both Alien and Aliens.

Where is Godzilla when you need him, no doubt on a sunny Maui beach.
